# Spring autowiring doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm trying to inject `messageSource` bean to one my component classes.

Here is part of bean xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mattis.test"/>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

And in my component I've got this:

```
@Component
public class TestClass {

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

<-- more code goes here -->
}
```

Always when I instantiate TestClass, messageSource is null. I tried more bean xml and class configurations but none of them worked.

Comment: How do you instanticate the `TestClass`, by `new`?

Answer (score 5):

You're manually calling `new TestClass()`. Spring autowiring only works on managed beans.